# Updated exposure variables in Stata

Tags: stata

I'm trying to create a variable for updated body mass index (`bmi`) through 4 visits of a study. I've tried the below but it only lists the value from the last visit. My data is in wide format where `visit_v1 = 1` if the participant was present for visit 1 and `bmi_v1 = bmi` at visit 1. I want `bmi_su` to equal `bmi_v1` if `visit_v1=1`, `bmi_v2 if visit_v2==1`, etc. Any thoughts where I'm going wrong?

```
gen bmi_su = .

replace bmi_su = bmi_v4 if visit_v4==1

replace bmi_su = bmi_v3 if visit_v3==1 & visit_v4==0

replace bmi_su = bmi_v2 if visit_v2==1 & visit_v4==0 & visit_v3==0

replace bmi_su = bmi_v1 if visit_v1==1 & visit_v4==0 & visit_v3==0 & visit_v2==0
```

Comment: Your problem seems simple but to me, unclear. Would you mind rephrasing and/or adding information on the data structure (toy example of how it is now and how you want it to be). You mention `bmi` in the text, but then it is not in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you seek something like this:

```
. clear all

. set more off

. 
. * Assumed data structure
. input ///
> id bmi visit1 visit2 visit3 bmi1 bmi2 bmi3

            id        bmi     visit1     visit2     visit3       bmi1       bmi2       bmi3
  1. 1 20 1 0 0 20 0 0
  2. 1 . 0 1 0 0 25 0
  3. 1 . 0 0 1 0 0 28
  4. end

. 
. list, noobs

  +----------------------------------------------------------+
  | id   bmi   visit1   visit2   visit3   bmi1   bmi2   bmi3 |
  |----------------------------------------------------------|
  |  1    20        1        0        0     20      0      0 |
  |  1     .        0        1        0      0     25      0 |
  |  1     .        0        0        1      0      0     28 |
  +----------------------------------------------------------+

. 
. * What you want?
. gen bmisu = bmi1 + bmi2 + bmi3

. 
. list, noobs

  +------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | id   bmi   visit1   visit2   visit3   bmi1   bmi2   bmi3   bmisu |
  |------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |  1    20        1        0        0     20      0      0      20 |
  |  1     .        0        1        0      0     25      0      25 |
  |  1     .        0        0        1      0      0     28      28 |
  +------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Panel or longitudinal data are usually much better off in a long data structure or shape (some say format).

In your case, the definitions imply that the last measurement will trump earlier measurements, so it is not clear why you seem surprised.

Here are some more systematic ways to do calculations. First,

```
gen bmi_su = bmi_v4 

forval j = 3(-1)1 { 
    replace bmi_su = bmi_v`j' if visit`j' 
}
```

Second,

```
gen bmi_su2 = bmi_v1 

forval j = 2/4 { 
   replace bmi_su2 = bmi_v`j' if visit`j' 
}
```

Consider also variants of the above with `if missing(bmi_su)` or `if missing(bmi_su2)` rather than the `if` conditions shown.